# Custom validation in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, error-handling, validation

I need to make a validation for a User model with the shortcut_url to fit a regular expression.

```
user.shortcut_url[/^[a-z]|[A-Z]*/]
```

I want it to throw an error and add to the messages for the User. I winged this without prior research and came up with

```
def validate_shortcut_url
 if self.shortcut_url
  if self.shortcut_url[/^[a-z]|[A-Z]*/] != ""
    return true
  else
    self.errors.full_messages << "Shortcut URL must begin with a letter"
    return false
  end
 end
end
```

Then put

```
validate :validate_shortcut_url
```

at the top of my model. Now. What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be long way around doing this
why wouldnt you just do

```
validates_format_of :validate_shortcut_url, :with => /^[a-z]|[A-Z]*/, :message => "Shortcut URL must begin with a letter"
```

Answer (score 1):

To run a custom validation, just call:

```
validate :validate_shortcut_url
```

in the model.  Also, since you are in the user model, you don't need to pass in a user - you can just use `self` as in `self.shortcut_url`

Comment: Gonna try it now. If it works, I'll make you a cookie. Or upvote you. Whichever you prefer

Comment: Nope. Kinda. Stopped runtime errors but doesn't really do anything. I'll edit with updated code.

Comment: Try adding:  errors.add :base, "Shortcut URL must begin with a letter"    I am assuming the regular expression part is working - I was only really addressing the "custom validation part."

Comment: And by adding i mean changing the line that says self.errors.full... to the one I mentioned.  Good luck!

Comment: Epic. Thanks. P.S. Netbeans hates me and decided to paste one line inside my RegEXP, don't know if you noticed that :)